# Does the large 6-pointed star on a sectional warn of dangerous radar facility?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts

I cannot find an explanation for this symbol on the chart legend.

Example: near BAB, Beale AFB, on the San Francisco Sectional Chart, does it warn of the dangerous radar facility?

[image]
Source: [skyvector.com](https://skyvector.com/?ll=39.13602556768472,-121.43682860968208&chart=301&zoom=3)

Comment: Note that the callout box is re radar hazard is connected by a dotted line to the large star.  Could be a good thing to note in the question or in an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two stars:

1. The large multi-pointed Star (6 pointed in this case) is described in the Aeronautical Chart User’s Guide as an indicator of High Energy Radiation Areas. The [Precision Acquisition Vehicle Entry Phased Array Warning System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAVE_PAWS) (radar) may be intense enough to damage avionics. Or, at least cause them to give false readings.
2. The blue star with the clear circle in its center indicates that the airfield has a rotating light beacon and the beacon’s location relative to the field. The beacon’s location can be used to differentiate one airfield from another while in flight at night.

Reference: [Aeronautical Chart User’s Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/)

Comment: No, not that symbol, it is a very large 5 point star with a 6 or 9 within it. It is adjacent to a caution box which warns of USAF PAWS radar hazard to aircraft.  I think the star calls attention to the PAWS, but an not certain,

Comment: Wow. I had to look closely at the small 5-pointed star to realize that it had a "clear circle" in the center. To me, it looked like a small outline of a 5-pointed star, much like the large 6-pointed star is an outline.  I see it now.

Comment: Then there's the third star, to the right of the control tower frequency, indicating that the control tower is part-time.